# Conditional module require inside an "If" still executed no matter what in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site

somehow this "require" still executed and error because file `mod.json` does not exist, the condition should not have met and should not get into the "if" block:

```js
const a = 1;
if(a === 2){
    const mod = require('./scripts/mod.json');
    ...
}
```

Any help and suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grave accent (`) instead.

If it still doesn't work, try something like:

```
const a = 1;
if(a === 2){
    const path = './scripts/mod.json'
    const mod = require(`$path`);
    ...
}
```

If it keeps solving the `require()`, try defining the `path` variable somewhere else (like `mounted`, or `created`), so the compiler can't easily find it.

If it keeps accessing the require, you might try to make sure that `a === 2`